# run functions when : window.scroll & window.resize & document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some functions ,

I need this functions run , when

> window.scroll
>
> window.resize
>
> document.ready

for example

```
<script>

    function myFunction1(data){ /*code*/ }
    function myFunction2(data){ /*code*/ }

    $(document).ready(function() {

         myFunction1(data);
         myFunction2(data);

    });

    $(window).resize(function() {

         myFunction1(data);
         myFunction2(data);

    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {

         myFunction1(data);
         myFunction2(data);

    });

<script>
```

so what would u guy suggest me to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(window).on("orientationchange load resize scroll", function () {
   myFunction1(data);
   myFunction2(data);
});
```

This will take care of orientation change as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following can be used.

```
function myFunction1(data){ /*code*/ }
function myFunction2(data){ /*code*/ }
function multipleHandle(data){
     myFunction1(data);
     myFunction2(data);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    multipleHandle(data)
});

$(window).on('resize scroll',function() {
    multipleHandle(data)
});
```

As an alternative, if `data` is a global variable,

```
function myFunction1(data){ /*code*/ }
function myFunction2(data){ /*code*/ }
function multipleHandle(){
     myFunction1(data);
     myFunction2(data);
}
$(document).ready(multipleHandle);

$(window).on('resize scroll',multipleHandle);
```